# jQuery .click function not working

Tags: jquery

I have a snippet of HTML that when a link is clicked, the div content becomes the linked div content.  The first function works fine.  It is the second click on #hidelink that jQuery doesn't seem to respond.  What am I missing here?

```
<div id="right">
    <div id='titletext'><p>||||||||||||||</p></div>
    <div id='presentation'></div>

    <div class='hidethisdiv'>
        <div id ="years">
            <h4><a id='resourceslink' href='#resources'>2010 Presentations</a></h4>
        </div>
        <div id='resources'>    
            <h4><a id='resourceslink' href='#resources'>2010 Presentations</a></h4>
            <p><a id='hidelink' href='#years'>&laquo;--back</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
  $('#mainmenu').fadeIn(2000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });

$('#presentation').html($('#years').html());

$( function() {
  $("#resourceslink").click(
    function () {
    $('#presentation').html($('#resources').html());
    }
   );

  $("#hidelink").click(
  function (){
    $('#presentation').html($('#years').html());
  }
  );
  //just add more divs like resources and a hidelink for new conferences
});
</script>
```

Comment: It seems like your last `$(function() { ...` chunk has not initiated. Try to remove the `$(function ()` part and just run those `$("resourceslink).click(...)`. If you need to wrap, try `($(function() {...})()` Hope that helps. Also, `id` cannot be assigned multiple times, use `class` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jquery hide and show as below also.

```
$("#hidelink").live('click',function () {

$('#resources').hide();

$('#years').show();

});
```

If you are using firefox as your browser,you can use firebug which is an add on.By putting break points on the scripts using firebug will get you an idea on what went wrong.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Don't use .live(), it's deprecated: http://api.jquery.com/live/ and it's not performant at all.

Answer (score 1):

First, an ID is unique. It must only exist once! In your example there is 2 x resourceslink.

If you have multiple element you want to group, use classes. Reminder: you can have multiple classes per element! For example

```
<a href="#hey" class="testing hello">heyhey</a>
```

You can call this with

```
$(".testing") - or - $(".testing.hello")  - or - $(".hello")
```

and attach events listener like this

```
$(".testing").on("click", function() { 
    doThis();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In your shown code you have a space between id and the value ;) also, ids are unique so having to a's with id="resourceslink" is bad practice :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `$('#resources').html()` the element is converted to html. You later read it in. The problem is you bound the click event to `#hidelink` befor the html is parsed. The event is linked to the hidden element instead.

One solution could be linking the click event after you added the content to `#presentation`. Another problem is that `#hidelink` is not unique anymore after adding the html to `#presentation`.

A better solution would be not to use `.html()`. Add all you elements to `#presentation` and hide them with `display: none`. Then bind the click events and use `.show()` and `.hide()` to display `#years` or `#resources`

Example:

```
<div id="right">
    <div id='presentation'>
        <div id ="years">
            <h4><a id='resourceslink' href='#resources'>2010 Presentations</a></h4>
        </div>
        <div id='resources' style="dislay: none">    
            <h4><a id='resourceslink' href='#resources'>2010 Presentations</a></h4>
            <p><a id='hidelink' href='#years'>&laquo;--back</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


$("#resourceslink").click(function () {
    $('#resources').show();
    $('#years').hide();
});

$("#hidelink").click(function () {
    $('#resources').hide();
    $('#years').show();
});
```

Comment: Why does this happen and how do I fix it?